export & import database
I need to export and import database from the old user to the new user through oracle apex or another Methode, how I can do that with detail please
I tried to make export database via cmd file, but I can't and get an error.

Apex isn't designed for that purpose.
Usually, we use

Data Pump Export & Import utilities

contra: they use Oracle directory, object created by SYS who then grants appropriate privileges to Oracle user who will be using it; files are then located in that directory (usually on a database server which means that you also have to have file system access to it)


the the original Export & Import

pro: you can run them on your own PC, files are stored locally




A simple example of the original exp; I'm exporting the whole scott user's schema.
c:\temp>exp scott/tiger@pdb1 file=scott.dmp log=scott_exp.log

Export: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 26 14:25:00 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

About to export specified users ...
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user SCOTT
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user SCOTT
About to export SCOTT's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export SCOTT's tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                          BONUS          0 rows exported
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
. . exporting table                            EMP         14 rows exported
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
. . exporting table                       SALGRADE          5 rows exported
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully with warnings.

c:\temp>

imp works the same way. For much more info, read documentation related to utility you're interested in and Oracle database version you use.

Alternatively, as it seems you also use SQL Developer, you can

choose "View - DBA" option from the menu
add a new connection (to user you're about to export or import) in the bottom left corner of the screen
right-click the "Data Pump" node
choose its "Data Pump Export Wizard" and follow instructions


Thank you for the reply. I tried to run the export commands through CMD, but I got an error, then I tried to use SQL Developer via DBA option and the export was successful
Now how can I import to another chart please? And where can I find the export file to use in the import process?
